# Which event should I use to add product to cart after coupon code is applied?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, addtocart

I'm developing a custom module on Magento 1.9.2.2 CE which will add a product to cart once a promo code is submitted by the customer. I've got my add product code working and triggering for other events:

```
$id = '2'; // Replace id with your product id
$qty = '1'; // Replace qty with your qty
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$cart->addProduct($_product, array('qty' => $qty));
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

I just need to know which event is appropriate for this situation. It appears to be *catalogrule_after_apply* but I'm getting mixed results. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`catalogrule` applies only for catalog promo rules, not for quote ones

There are many possibilities

One of them could be observing `checkout_cart_save_after` event, and then check if the quote has the concrete coupon and then check if you've added before your promo product to the quote. Once you have `$cart` in your observer, you can check both with...

```
$cart->getQuote()->getCouponCode()
$cart->getItems()
```